# Cannot import class even though dependency is installed

Tags: java, import, jar, dependencies, alpha-vantage

I am trying to use the alpha vantage scraper api from https://github.com/mainstringargs/alpha-vantage-scraper. I believe i have the dependency but i cannot import the class into my program. I have also tried installing the Jar file but that also dint help. Does anyone have any ideas to help? thanks

Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.computing</groupId>
    <artifactId>ComputingNEA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ComputingNEA</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper</groupId>
            <artifactId>alpha-vantage-scraper</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.computing.computingnea/com.computing.computingnea.Main
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the code:

```
public class ApiData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ApiUrl = "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com";
        URL url = new URL(ApiUrl);

        String apiKey = "14b6cacbe7msh743e555ffddd42dp1";
        int timeout = 3000;
        AlphaVantageConnector apiConnector = new AlphaVantageConnector(apiKey, timeout);
        TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = new TimeSeries(apiConnector);
        try {
            IntraDay response = stockTimeSeries.intraDay("MSFT", Interval.ONE_MIN, OutputSize.COMPACT);
            Map<String, String> metaData = response.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Information: " + metaData.get("1. Information"));
            System.out.println("Stock: " + metaData.get("2. Symbol"));

            List<StockData> stockData = response.getStockData();
            stockData.forEach(stock -> {
                System.out.println("date:   " + stock.getDateTime());
                System.out.println("open:   " + stock.getOpen());
                System.out.println("high:   " + stock.getHigh());
                System.out.println("low:    " + stock.getLow());
                System.out.println("close:  " + stock.getClose());
                System.out.println("volume: " + stock.getVolume());
            });
        } catch (AlphaVantageException e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have posted a screen shot with a host address and an api key. Probably not what you want all of us to see.

Comment: Now for the issue itself. Please do not post code as images. Paste them as text (and format them accordingly) in the question instead.

Comment: I was just showing you that the class could not be imported. and okay, i will edit my question

Comment: If you provide all the necessary code as text it is easier for us to help you as we can work on reproducing the issue if we would like to by copying what you have done so far. That is one reason why text is preferred over images.

Comment: okay Just edited it so all my code is here

Comment: it might be a problem regarding the JAR files and adding the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I successfully built this program with `mvn clean package`. The missing jar `alpha-vantage-scraper-1.5.1.jar` was downloaded to my local maven repository. The only changes I had to make for the program to actually run was to change `String ApiUrl = "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com"` to `String ApiUrl = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com"`, and to catch exception `MalformedURLException`. I made no changes to the pom.

To make it easier for someone else to reproduce this I attach the modified program together with the imports which are not that obvious.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.AlphaVantageConnector;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.TimeSeries;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.output.AlphaVantageException;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.output.timeseries.IntraDay;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.output.timeseries.data.StockData;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.input.timeseries.Interval;
import io.github.mainstringargs.alphavantagescraper.input.timeseries.OutputSize;

public class ApiData 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String ApiUrl = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(ApiUrl);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("bad URL");
        }

        String apiKey = "14b6cacbe7msh743e555ffddd42dp1";
        int timeout = 3000;
        AlphaVantageConnector apiConnector = new AlphaVantageConnector(apiKey, timeout);
        TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = new TimeSeries(apiConnector);
        try {
            IntraDay response = stockTimeSeries.intraDay("MSFT", Interval.ONE_MIN, OutputSize.COMPACT);
            Map<String, String> metaData = response.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Information: " + metaData.get("1. Information"));
            System.out.println("Stock: " + metaData.get("2. Symbol"));

            List<StockData> stockData = response.getStockData();
            stockData.forEach(stock -> {
                System.out.println("date:   " + stock.getDateTime());
                System.out.println("open:   " + stock.getOpen());
                System.out.println("high:   " + stock.getHigh());
                System.out.println("low:    " + stock.getLow());
                System.out.println("close:  " + stock.getClose());
                System.out.println("volume: " + stock.getVolume());
            });
        } catch (AlphaVantageException e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```